# Spring CLI command not found?

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line-interface

I have a superclass which implements `CommandMarker`. Some children appears as an usable command, but this one does not.

The log says:

```
10:29:01.128 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'abortCommand'
....
10:29:01.230 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'abortCommand'
```

I found no errors while creating the bean, but when I try to use the command I get

```
Command 'abort' not found (for assistance press TAB)
```

I tagged the corresponding method with `@CliCommand(value = "abort", help = "blah")`

Comment: Could you share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I was thinking hard how to do it, as I didn't see a point in sharing the bodies of the methods in question. Again, sharing the parent made no sense (to me) as the children inherited everything just the same. I managed to figure it out; the source of my issue rooted in a far more dumber problem: I forgot to declare the corresponding method as public :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems that a method tagged with `@CliCommand` must be public to be visible for spring, tagging the class as `@Component` is not sufficient.